# Real Analysis and Measure Theory exercises

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I hope asking this kind of questions is accepted in this forum, if not I apologize in advance:) .

In order to better understand the mathematical foundation of Probability theory I'm reading the book "Real Analysis" 4th edition by Royden and Fitzpatrick, in my opinion an excellent book to introduce you to the topic. After each chapter, there are some exercises to make you put in practise the theory learned so far, not too many though and I feel like I need something more "Exercises book"-like in order to better grasp the theory. On the web I found out that the Professor Fitzpatrick has a web page with other exercises and solutions, that unfortunately are not public. I wonder if anybody has got or can suggest something similar to keep practising, very detailed as the exercises proposed by him, possibly on pdf format that is more easy to access.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A good option is ''Espaços Métricos'' by Elon Lages Lima.  It is in portuguese though.

Another good option is ''Metric Spaces'' by Míchéal O Searcóid.

Comment: statmathbc.wordpress.com might help.